# A central force which enables a torque on a sphere - is it still conservative?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, energy-conservation

Consider the following example:

[image]

Two spheres (one big, other small) standing vertically on ground.
At first, the small sphere is on top of the big sphere.
Then, it starts to roll w/o slipping to the right by the gravitational force ($m\vec{g}$).

Let's define:

- point **A**, where $\theta = 0$
- point **B**, where $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Does the energy conserved between A and B?

I think that it's not conserved, because of the rotational kinetic energy of the small sphere $\left(\frac{1}{2}I \omega^2\right)$.

Comment: It is.The work done by static friction is zero, so none of the energy is dissipated. (Since you assume it is rolling without slipping.)

Comment: But how would you revert the process to obtain merely the potential energy it had in point $A$?

Comment: I'll leave that up for someone else, but the energy gained by the body is only a result of the gravitational force (both Kinetic and Rotational). Hence the conservativeness.

Comment: @Dor how would you revert the process? Put another big sphere somewhere on the path of the small sphere, i.e. at some distance from your big sphere, and take care that the surface on which the big spheres stand, be frictionless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a conservative field (no dissipation of energy) whatever way follows the small sphere, i.e. rolling along another sphere, or other, the total energy (kinetic + potential + rotational) is conserved.